# Trouble decrypting bytes with ECB mode encryption

Tags: python, rust, cryptography, aes

I'm having trouble decrypting a byte string using the openssl crate. As a heads up this is for the Cryptopals challenges, specifically set 2 problem 2. The text file has been encrypted using AES with CBC mode, but I guess a single block can be decrypted with ECB.

I've already tried decrypting the entire `10.txt` file with CBC mode, and I know that works. I've also used the following Python code to verify that ECB decryption of the sames bytes also works.

For Python 3:

```python
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def main():
    key = b'YELLOW SUBMARINE'
    with open("10.txt") as input_file:
        data = b64decode(input_file.read())

    data = data[0:AES.block_size]
    print(data)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    x = cipher.decrypt(data)
    print(x)
    return
```

For Rust:

```rust
extern crate openssl;

use openssl::symm::decrypt;
use openssl::symm::{encrypt, Cipher};

static KEY: &'static [u8] = b"YELLOW SUBMARINE";

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // No idea why this OpenSSL call doesn't work.
    let data = b"\x09\x12\x30\xaa\xde\x3e\xb3\x30\xdb\xaa\x43\x58\xf8\x8d\x2a\x6c";
    let cipher = Cipher::aes_128_ecb();
    let new_data = decrypt(cipher, KEY, None, data);
    println!("error {:?}", new_data);

    Ok(())
}
```

I expected to see this function decrypt the byte string in Rust the same way it has been done in python.

Comment: ECB mode does of course not use an IV (and it sits all alone in your Python code, poor IV). OpenSSL always expects PKCS#7 compatible padding by default.

Comment: I fixed the code issue and my misleading comment about the initialization vector. Thanks for pointing those out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL is telling you that your input is not correctly padded.  Change the input to

```
let data = b"\x09\x12\x30\xaa\xde\x3e\xb3\x30\xdb\xaa\x43\x58\xf8\x8d\x2a\x6c\x60\xfa\x36\x70\x7e\x45\xf4\x99\xdb\xa0\xf2\x5b\x92\x23\x01\xa5";
```

and you’ll see that your code decrypts it correctly.

If you need to disable padding, you can do that by using a [`Crypter`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.16/openssl/symm/struct.Crypter.html) object and calling `.pad(false)` on it ([example](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.16/src/openssl/symm.rs.html#792)).

Comment: Pardon the silly question, but how did you arrive at those last 16 bytes? I would have expected a padding to be needed at the end of the byte stream, given a text file that isn't length mod 16 == 0. So I'm confused as to why the last half isn't a continuation of the contents in 10.txt
Thank you very much.

Comment: @jdim `printf "I'm back and I'm" | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K 59454c4c4f57205355424d4152494e45`. At least 1 byte of padding is always added (when enabled), even for lengths divisible by the block size, because otherwise it would be ambiguous whether the padding should be removed upon decryption.

Comment: Got it, as per [this RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3). Much appreciated.